# How can I change this function to display only twice articles?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this page in Wordpress:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

**CODE PHP:**

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=16');
$count = 0;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $count++;
    if ($count == 1) {  ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-height" >
                <div class="text-box-right">
                    <div class="title-home"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

                    <div class="content-home"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-height" >
                <div class="prod-box-left">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('news'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><div class="content-home"><?php the_content(); ?></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
        </div>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <?php $count = 0; ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-height" >
                <div class=" prod-box-right">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('news'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-height">
                <div class="text-box-right">
                    <div class="title-home"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div class="conteont-home"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is that some items are displayed twice ... and I just want to be displayed at the bottom.

I put a picture to better understand what I mean.

[image]

What is wrong with my function?
Do you think you can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When your if statement is true for `if ($count == 1)` the block of code that is used has the function `the_content()` twice. I imagine this is why you're getting duplicate content. Remove one of those functions to eliminate the repetion.

Answer (score 0):

you would normally see the latest 10 posts. If you want to show only 2 posts, you can use query_posts() like so:

```
<?php 
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=2' );
?>
```

So you have use like this.

```
query_posts( 'cat=16&posts_per_page=2' );
```

For more reference, see the **Wordpress** function **query_posts()** documentation at following link -https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts.